# Does IIS log in-flight requests when you perform an IIS reset?

Tags: iis, iis-8

If an IIS reset is performed, do requests that are currently being processed, but not yet completed, get logged in the IIS Logs?

And, requests that have been completed but not yet flushed to the log file, do these still get written to the file?

Answer (score 1):

I guess not, as all in-memory session states are also lost. According to Microsoft documentation on [Start or Stop the Web Server (IIS 8)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635851.aspx):

> You can stop IIS when you want to stop the web server from serving
>   content, such as when you upgrade applications. To stop the web
>   server, you must stop the Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) and
>   the World Wide Web Publishing Service (W3SVC). You can then start the
>   web server when you are ready for the web server to serve content
>   again.
>
> When you stop WAS and W3SVC, **all sessions connected to your web server**
>   **are dropped. Any in-memory session state is lost.** All sites are
>   unavailable until these services are restarted. Therefore, avoid
>   stopping and restarting your web server if you can.

About [IIS Reset Activity](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc734986%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

> IISreset.exe is a command-line utility that can be used to stop,
>   start, and restart IIS Internet services.
>
> Note:  Restarting or stopping IIS, or rebooting your Web server, is a
>   severe action. When you use IISreset, your Web sites and applications
>   become unavailable, **all sessions connected to your Web server are**
>   **dropped, and you lose existing state in your applications. Changes to**
>   **the metabase can be lost.** Your Web sites and applications will be
>   unavailable until the affected Internet services are restarted.
>
> The IISreset command stops and restarts the IIS Admin Service, the
>   Windows Process Activation Service (WAS), and the World Wide Web
>   Publishing Service (WWW Service).
>
> Avoid using IISreset unless absolutely necessary. Instead, first try
>   to restart an individual Web site or an individual application pool
>   that may be causing problems.

[IIS Logging overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525410%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> ... When a
>   loggable event, usually an HTTP transaction, occurs, IIS calls the
>   selected logging module, which then writes to one of the logs stored
>   in %SystemRoot%\system32\Logfiles\.

As far as I can see, first of all, an HTTP transcation has to be completed to be logged and then the logging service must also run untill it is finished with writing it. So there is a gray area in between the stop and start for the in-flight requestes and very little chance to be writtten fully to log. It also depends on how long the related services will wait before shutting down.

Comment: Yep, session state would be lost if using in-process session state, but I can't find anything on specifically IIS Logs (as opposed to session state)

Comment: Yes, it is not clearly mentioned. But as far as I understand, in between the service stop and start, not all will be logged. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

IIS reset perform a clean service restart, as such the log file is closed correctly.

Its not like you kill the process. (or if the restart cant complete due to problematic extension, as the process will hang up and finish killed too in that case)

Comment: Well, I'm not quite sure if iis reset is going to do somthing different: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22084561/difference-between-iisreset-and-iis-stop-start-command

Comment: @bangal the link confirm my post, the default behavior is restart, thus a service restart.

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @bangal You use my answer to update yours, no credit and you tell me to see it ? Strange world

Comment: first of all the link doesn't confirm your answer. I have doubt if you have read it. It clearly says there is no such difference between iisreset and iis stop and start -quote " IISReset as suit of commands that helps you manage IIS start / stop etc".  A reset is no magical command, it means combination of stop and then start. If you could take some time to read the highlighted parts of my answer, you will see that, I'm just trying to point to that fact since you mentioned it. If you also read a little down further, you will see, I have not changed my position.